# Does gnome support desktop widgets?

Tags: gnome, widgets

Does gnome support desktop widgets? Any analogue to KDE plasmoids, Vista/Win7 sidebar/desktop widgets, Mac OS X dashboard widgets, etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can actually install and run plasma from Gnome if you so desire. It should work, despite having a lot of KDE dependencies, just add it to the startup programs. I am testing this right now, if you would like this option, I will report back to you.

There are also a few programs in the software center that allow you to use desktop applets. Search for **gdesklets** and **screenlets**. Here are articles:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screenlets

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gdesklets

Linux is quite modular. :)

Comment: Thanks. I think it'd be nice if you share the most significant moments of your experience with Plasma right here.

Comment: Works pretty great actually! If you do not mind all the KDE installed, it fits well. Just run: sudo apt-get install plasma-desktop. When it is finished, press alt+f2 and type: plasma-desktop. When prompted between GDM and KDM choose GDM.

Go to System -> Preferences -> System Settings for the KDE control panel. Under appearance you can change the KDE style to GTK. Screenshot: http://ubuntuone.com/p/HLc/

Answer (score 3):

Screenlets and gDesklets are no longer maintained so I created flidget, a flexible, lightweight and concise widget system:

https://github.com/mrubioroy/flidget

Comment: This seems nice. But unfortunately the console widgets are all only about 20 pixels wide on my Focal desktop, no matter how I set the width. So it's sadly not useful.

Answer (score 2):

I like Screenlets (from standard repos) . Much better then gDesklets for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you want use KDE Plasma Widget (Plasmoid) maybe you can look my answer in this Question [Run Plasma Widget in Gnome](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38830/does-unity-have-any-widgets/49699#49699) :)