# Does Unity have any widgets?

Tags: unity, widgets

While upgrading to Ubuntu 11.04, my google-gadgets framework was removed. I thought at the time this is because it's deprecated because there's some alternative integrated in the new unity framework, but I couldn't find any.

Are there any RSS/clock/etc. widgets in Unity? If not - why did the upgrade uninstalled my google gadgets app?
What do I do now?

Thanks.

Comment: Unity doesn't have any widgets but you can display clock, weather, calendar, system monitor etc. on desktop by using Conky. [This page on Google+](http://plus.google.com/communities/104794997718869399105/stream/c411c91a-2e51-4666-b3cc-13caf1c2dfc9) has some good examples

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, it does not have any widgets you can place on the desktop.

The uninstall was probably because it was installed from a standalone deb and apt marked it as obsolete after the switch to the 11.04 ppas.

Answer (score 16):

You can use KDE Plasma Widget (Plasmoids)
This is screenshot my desktop using Plasmoids
[image: Screenshot]
For catch that, just follow this steps

1. Install Plasma Desktop and dependencies

   > > sudo apt-get install plasma-desktop, plasma-scriptengine-python
2. Make launcher for launch the Plasma Desktop.
   [image: Create Launcher]
3. If you want to use it from startup just add it in "Startup Applications"
   [image: Make Startup]
4. And then, make things look right. First enable GTK+ for Qt Application via :

   > System Settings (for KDE) -> Appliaction Appearance -> Widget Style -> GTK+
5. Next, install Ambiance theme style for the Plasma

   > System Settings (for KDE) -> Workspace Appearance -> Desktop Theme -> Get new theme
   >   [image: Search Ambiance theme]
6. Finally, improve your new desktop with Unity+Plasma. For Launching and adding Widget, same like in KDE ^_^
7. If you want the Widget work in behind Desktop (like Dashboard in OSX)

   > [image: Setting Widget behavior]
8. And you will get like this in Ubuntu!!

   > [image: Plasma Dashboard]

Ok.. I get that things all from [Install Plasma in Unity](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/05/how-to-run-kde-plasma-widgets-in-ubuntu-unity/)

I hope you look for like this

Comment: Thanks for this.  IMO - the Plasma desktop is the best part of KDE and having it under Gnome is pure awesome.  Kudos to the KDE folks for make thier stuff so modular...impressive.

Comment: whats the point running plasma on gnome ?
why not just use kde ?

Answer (score 11):

Install [screenlets [image: Install screenlets]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/screenlets), then open `screenlets-manager`.

[image: Screenshot]

It allows you to run not only the Google gadgets you are looking for, but also gadgets and widgets from other frameworks (such as Super Karamba) :)!

Comment: I just installed this. It seems to be awesome, considering how easy it was to get it to work.(Ubuntu 14.04 x86_64)

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple of indicator applets you can install. Take a look at this fred... [What Application Indicators are available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30334/list-of-application-indicators)

Answer (score 0):

You can use flidget (I created it). It is a flexible and highly configurable widget system. You can find it at:

https://github.com/mrubioroy/flidget