# How do I use Plasma widgets in Unity?

Tags: unity, 11.10, plasma

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I resolve unmet dependencies?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies)

I have already read [Does Unity have any widgets?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38830/does-unity-have-any-widgets) and the article on OMGubuntu but `apt-get` and `synaptic` cannot find `plasma-desktop` and they throw an error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
    plasma-scriptengine-python : Depends: python-qt4-dbus (>= 4.8.3-3~) but
    it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I am really wanting to get Plasma desktop but I am unsure of how to continue.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?