# Is there any alternative for Windows gadgets in Ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, software-recommendation, widgets

I am new to Ubuntu and would very much like to see a weather gadget (aka widgets).

[image: weather widget windows]

Can anyone recommed a simple add-that could give me a little weather, Clock, Twitter Crawl, etc?

Thanks

Comment: When referring to Windows it is always best to include an image explaining what you are looking for. (and yes you can not create images yet: just dump the link into your question and someone will edit it so it included the IMG tags) ;)

Comment: Sorry @Rinzwind I just assumed that folks would just google it :P  I'll make a note of this.

Comment: I would not be able to pick out the windows 7 weather gadget from any other weather gadget unless it had a big red blinking arrow next to it ;)

Comment: Allow me to assist, sans red arrow. ![img](http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC368504.png)

Comment: I always wondered who uses those widget :-D I guess there is some fans

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no widgets for Unity, but when you have KDE you can install Plasmoids as explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38830/does-unity-have-any-widgets)

You also can install Conky to show weather info on you desktop, but this can be a bit harder to do.

[A google search](https://www.google.nl/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=conky%20weather#hl=nl&sclient=psy-ab&q=conky%20weather%20ubuntu&oq=conky%20weather%20&aq=1&aqi=g2&aql=&gs_l=serp.11.1.0l2.8195.8195.1.10335.1.0.1.0.0.0.0.0..0.0...0.0.dwUtqtxXCic&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=e48206c01504ddb4&biw=1600&bih=788&pf=p&pdl=300)

Answer (score 22):

There are few options:

1. **[Screenlets](http://screenlets.org/index.php/Home)**

   Screenlets are the Linux alternative for "Windows Gadgets". Screenlets are small owner-drawn applications (written in Python) that can be described as "the virtual representation of things lying/standing around on your desk". Sticky notes, clocks, rulers, ... the possibilities are endless.

   [image]

   Hare's a preview of a weather screenlet:

   [image]

   To install *Screenlets*, open terminal by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and run following commands:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install screenlets
   ```

   To install a complete pack of *Screenlets*:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install screenlets-pack-all
   ```

   Some sources to download *Screenlets*: [Gnome-look](http://gnome-look.org/index.php?xcontentmode=6700), [KDE-look](http://kde-look.org/index.php?xcontentmode=38).
2. **[Cairo-Dock](http://www.glx-dock.org/)**

   Cairo-Dock is an attractive, Lightweight eye-candy dock to launch your applications. I'm mentioning it hare because of it's ability to add add-ons. It comes bundled with
   many applets including this weather applet. You can use applets inside dock or detach and use them as gadgets.

   [image]

   To install *Cairo-Dock*, open terminal by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and run following command:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install cairo-dock
   ```

   You can find some third party add-ons [hare](http://www.glx-dock.org/mc_album.php?a=8).
3. **[Conky](http://conky.sourceforge.net/)**

   Conky is an advanced, Highly configurable system monitor for Linux. It's little hard to configure, Specially for new users. Hare's an example of conky

   [image]

   Follow these steps to setup `HTC Conky`:

   1. To install *Conky*, open terminal by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and run one of following commands:

      To install a standard *conky*:

      ```
      sudo apt-get install conky-std
      ```

      To install a full *conky* with most compile options enabled:

      ```
      sudo apt-get install conky-all
      ```
   2. Download [Conky HTC Home](http://browse.deviantart.com/?order=5&q=conky#/d4lsxmz) and extract it.
   3. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to show hidden files. Copy ".conky" from downloaded folder to your home directory.
   4. Open the "fonts" folder and copy all the fonts to Home/.fonts/
   5. Go to [AccuWeather](http://www.accuweather.com/) and find your location and copy web address.
   6. open Home/.conky/htc_home/accuweather/accuw_script with text editor and replace the location address with the web address you just copied from AccuWeather.

[image]

To put conky into startup applications, Hit super key (Windows key) and search for "starup applications" and open it.

[image]

Click on add, and fill respective fields as follow:

```
Name: HTC - Conky  
Command: bash -c "sleep 15; conky -c $HOME/.Conky/htc_home/conkyrc"  
Comment: Conky
```

and save it.

To start Conky for the first time, Hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and run the following command:

`conky -c ~/.Conky/htc_home/conkyrc`

That's it...!

For more Coky themes visit: [DeviantArt](http://browse.deviantart.com/?q=conky), [Arch Forums](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=39906), [Web UPD8](http://www.webupd8.org/search/label/conky?max-results=10), [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=281865).

Comment: Thanks a lot for suggesting **Screenlets**!
I was really tired of **conky** manual tweaks and difficult problems like displaying sometimes a larger white or black canvas underneath its fake-transparent window, which sometimes included a notification message as well.
I also tried **My Weather Indicator** but it also has numerous bugs.
I will appreciate very much if you can also specify **the source of that 3rd party weather screenlet** in your screenshot.

Comment: @Sadi You're welcom!... That screenlet is part of `screenlets-pack-all` package. You can install it by running: `sudo apt-get install screenlets-pack-all` or search for it in Software Center.

Comment: Thanks, but there's only **FreeMeteoWeather** in that package. I later found out that it's probably **Clear Weather** screenlet which seems no longer maintained/updated, and there's only Chinese version called **China Clear Weather** at the moment.

Comment: @Sadi Yes it's called `Clear Weather` and actually it is part of that package, It's on my desktop right now. You must be missing something... Did you restarted `Screenlets` after installing that package?

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot, it seems I've got only basic pack installed, now I've got it all, thanks again.

Answer (score 8):

[Plexydesk](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/09/plexydesk-ubuntu-linux-widgets) is frigging awesome. This app creats an environment for widgets for Ubuntu, like Plasma of KDE.

Don't ever bother of Screenlets or gDesklets, they are out-of-dated.

[image]

Comment: But isn't there a nice weather widget to show off? ;-)

Answer (score 5):

I installed conky-Lua.

[image]

Step by step instructions are in http://xchamitha.blogspot.co.uk/2012/11/adding-gadgets-to-ubuntu-1210-desktop.html

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu with Unity has no widgets, instead they have indicators. Application indicators provide a simple and effective API to provide an application icon in the notification area in the top-right part of the screen, and provide simple, accessible, and complete access to key parts of your application.

### [**My Weather Indicator**](https://launchpad.net/my-weather-indicator)

**Category:** *Weather Forecasting*

this is an indicator that will show weather information in your area, as well as other valuable information such as time of sunrise, sunset and moon phase

[image]

Find out whether you need to wear a jacket, a t-shirt or a waterproof suit... If you click on the indicator, you will get more information about, humidity, dew point, feels like, wind velocity and wind direction, weather condition.

My-Weather-Indicator informs you about sunrise ans sunset time, and the lunar phase

[image: Information]

You can get the forecast for your area for next three days:

[image: The forecast]

You can get information of the weather of two cities at the same time:

[image: Two cities]

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:atareao/atareao
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install my-weather-indicator
```

### [Hardware Sensors Indicator](https://launchpad.net/indicator-sensors)

**Category:** *System Information*

Application Indicator showing hardware sensors.

[image: sensors]

First add the repository:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:alexmurray/indicator-sensors
```

Update:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

And then install the package:

```
sudo apt-get install indicator-sensors
```

Then launch `Hardware Sensors Indicator` from Unity or run `indicator-sensors` from a terminal.

### [Skype indicator](http://www.skype.com/)

[image: Screenshot]

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ $(lsb_release -sc) partner"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install skype
```

A list of available indicators [What Application Indicators are available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30334/what-application-indicators-are-available)

Answer (score 0):

I was elated to see gKrellm avail for 12.04.  Its not quite as flashy as the windows 7 widgets, but will do almost all the same things.

Just open up the software center and search gkrellm.

I know they have a weather plugin, but afaik there is not a twitter crawl.

Comment: I like gkrellm ... it just works !

Answer (score 0):

Use the below command in terminal to install gadgets in ubuntu

**sudo apt-get install screenlets screenlets-pack-all**

Comment: I see `screenlets` only for 14.04 LTS  (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=screenlets)