# Need a simple program to poll and display language in X

Tags: software-recommendation

I need a simple program to display information for me on screen.  For example, I want a tiny box in the corner to tell me what the current language is.

I envision that the program would just run a script every few seconds or otherwise get updated.

I use fvwm, not gnome or other window managers that have a dock so I need something that will work with a vanilla Xwindows.

Is there something like this?

Comment: Try Conky? http://askubuntu.com/a/134640/158442

Answer (score 0):

Normally the current language is displayed in the system tray by the input method editor.  For example, ibus or fcitx.  And if you have a system tray application, it will be in there.

If you wanted to get the layout without using the input method, you could shell out to setxkbmap such as from [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12072/how-do-i-get-current-keyboard-layout).

Whatever commands you want to run you could either do it from FvwmScript or just update a button in FvwmButtons.

For just the language one, add this to your fvwm config:

```
DestroyModuleConfig FvwmButtonLanguage: *
*FvwmButtonLanguage: (Id button0, Title "ZZ")
```

Then you can either schedule a periodic task for it (also in your fvwm config):

```
Schedule 1000 PipeRead "echo SendToModule FvwmButtonLanguage ChangeButton button0 Title $(setxkbmap -query | grep layout | cut -f2 -d: )"
```

Or run a script (assuming you have Module FvwmCommandS loaded in your start function) to update the button that contains the following:

```
 while true ; do FvwmCommand "SendToModule FvwmButtonLanguage ChangeButton button0 Title $(setxkbmap -query | grep layout | cut -f2 -d: )" ; sleep 1 ; done
```

If you update your question to provide another example, I'll update this answer with a thorough example.